# Keep getting error: '.class' expected line 40

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab04B {
    public static String toMeters (int unitNumber) {
        String value;
        switch (unitNumber) {
            case 1:
                value = "Meter";
            break;
            case 2:
                value = "Nautical mile";
            break;
            case 3:
                value = "Furlong";
            break;
            case 4: 
                value = "Mil";
            break;
            case 5:
                value = "Rod";
            break;
            case 6:
                value = "Vershok";
            break;
            case 7:
                value = "Sheppey";
            break;
            case 8:
                return 1.702;
            default:
                return -1;
        }

        {
    public static double fromMeters (int unitNumber)
    {
        switch (unitNumber)
        {
            case 1:
                return 1;

            case 2:
                return 1/1852.0;    

            case 3:
                return 1/201.168;

            case 4: 
                return 1/0.0254;

            case 5:
                return 1/5.029;

            case 6:
                return 1/0.04445;

            case 7:
                return 1/1408.0;

            case 8:
                return 1/1.702;

            default:
                return -1;
        }   
            {
    public static String getUnitName (int unitNumber)
    {
        String value;
        switch (unitNumber)
        {
            case 1:
                value = "Meter";


            case 2:
                value = "Nautical mile";

            case 3:
                value = "Furlong";


            case 4: 
                value = "Mil";


            case 5:
                value = "Rod";


            case 6:
                value = "Vershok";


            case 7:
                value = "Sheppey";


            case 8:
                value = "Smoot";


            default:
                value = "faulty input";

        } 
        {
            public static void main (String[] args)

                Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

                System.out.println("Converting Measurements");
                System.out.println("By: Ashleigh Pacewicz");
                System.out.println("1.\tMeter");
                System.out.println("2.\tNautical Mile");
                System.out.println("3.\tFurlong");
                System.out.println("4.\tMil");
                System.out.println("5.\tRod");
                System.out.println("6.\tVershok");
                System.out.println("7.\tSheppey");
                System.out.println("8.\tSmoot");
                System.out.println("From what unit would you like to convert? ");
                int = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("To what unit would you like to convert? ");
                int = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print("What measurement would you like to convert? ");
                double = input.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}
```

I am just learning how to code. I'm trying to write a program to convert meters but I keep receiving error on line 40 and line 63 and line 96. Error:

> '.class' expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Indentation is your friend and will show you where the error is.

Comment: i think one of those `{` needs to be a `}`

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
 int = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("To what unit would you like to convert? ");
            int = input.nextInt();
```

You didn't give them a name

and look at your braces

```
 }   
        {
public static String getUnitName (int unitNumber)
{
```

It's the same at every method

it should be like this

```
public void methodName() {

}
```

but you're doing this

```
{
public void methodName()
{
```

and you forgot breaks;

1 more thing you should really use an IDE

Answer (score 1):

I want to be honest. I do not know why you are getting this error...

I've just copied your code and compiled. After removing 2 to 3 braces and adding one, your code compiled without errors. I'm sure you are getting the error, you pasted into your question, from somewhere else.

You have to apply some fixes:

```
System.out.println("To what unit would you like to convert? ");
int NAME_YOUR_VARS = input.nextInt();
```

And in a few places you are placing open braces infront of method headers:

```
{
public static double fromMeters(int unitNumber){
```

Or you forgot to close method bodys:

```
public static String toMeters (int unitNumber) {

    switch(unitNumber) {
    /* case statements were cut out here*/
    }
//<- Here you forgot a brace!
```

Keeping track of code blocks and brace placing is very important!